# Any way to initialize a vector of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, unique-ptr, initializer-list

For example

```
struct A
{
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> m_vector { make_unique<int>(1), make_unique<int>(2) };
};
```

I try above but failed. Any way to initialize a vector of unique_ptr?

Comment: What error message? What compiler?

Comment: Initializer lists don't work with move-only types. Your only solution is to construct the vector empty and then use `push_back` or `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't move from an initializer list because the elements are `const`.  §8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]/p5:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an
>   initializer list as if the implementation allocated an array of `N`
>   elements of type `const E`, where N is the number of elements in the
>   initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with
>   the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the
>   `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that
>   array.

You can only copy, but you can't copy a `unique_ptr` since it's move-only.

You'd have to use `push_back` or `emplace_back` etc. to fill the vector after you construct it.