# Would the removal of "const" in dcl.init.list#5 cause havoc in the standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unique-ptr, initializer-list, c++23

Once more I wrote this code

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> v{ std::make_unique<Foo>(), std::make_unique<Foo>() };
```

and then realized it's probably the fifth time. That line doesn't compile because of [[dcl.init.list#5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#5) (I have also already come across [the relevant question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827435/any-way-to-initialize-a-vector-of-unique-ptr)¹):

> An object of type `std​::​initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation generated and materialized ([conv.rval]) a prvalue of type “array of *N* `const E`”

But it is so natural to expect that that line works, so my question is:

##### What would go wrong if one wanted to change that part of the standard in a way that makes that line of code work?

I'm not referring to changes to the standard of the form *There's an exception to [dcl.init.list#5] for the case above*, but to actually make take [dcl.init.list#5] and remove that `const`.

Existing code could break I guess, but would a lot more in the standard have to change to cope with the change I'm imagining?

---

(¹) And I'm also aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077079/why-does-c-make-the-element-type-of-stdinitializer-list-const), but the answer, I believe, doesn't really address the *why*.

Comment: Did you mean `std::make_unique<Foo>()` instead of `std::make_unique(Foo{})`?

Comment: The first comment to the last linked question seems to answer your question. As I know, that proposal P0065 is not accepted because the issue is solvable with variable templates since C++14.

Comment: @273K, yep, I missed that!

Comment: [A proposal](https://wg21.link/p2752) to allow the backing array to be stored in static read-only memory, and reused for repreated initializations, has alredy been approved for C++26. Seems like removing const would break that.

Comment: It's not just a const, it's a **constexpr**.  And yes, that would break code, so what you propose is not going to happen anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `const` there wouldn't make your code well-formed. The `reference_type` of the iterator produced by `std::initializer_list::begin` is still a `const` lvalue reference instead of a rvalue reference as you would need here.

Removing `const` there will, I think, have no negative impact on any program behavior, however it would disallow the compiler from assuming that the elements of the initializer list won't be modified, i.e. it would prevent generally putting the array in read-only memory if the elements are constant-initialized.

---

Correction for the answer above: I can think of one exception with regards to constant evaluation.

Currently it doesn't seem clear to me in the standard whether

```
constexpr std::initializer_list<T> i = {1,2,3};
constexpr T j = *i.begin();
```

is supposed to be well-formed for any given type `T`. If it is supposed to be well-formed for some types, then certainly the backing array must be `const`-qualified to avoid contradictions.